# Can we create Training Job from an 'in progress' Labeling Job?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ground-truth

I have created a labeling job using AWS Ground Truth with the following details:

- Task type: bounding boxes
- Dataset type: images
- Total dataset objects: 36,000

**Objective**: I would like to create a training job from the so far labeled data (~5000/36,000)

**Issue**: The 'LabelingJobOutput' hasn't been generated because the labeling job is not complete so I cannot make use of this [notebook](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-aws-greengrass-custom-object-detection-model/blob/master/training/01_Process%20SageMaker%20Ground%20Truth%20labeling%20job%20outputs%20for%20training.ipynb) that I'm following.

Is there a workaround this?

Comment: From reading the unclear and distributed AWS documentation along with other resources, I do not think it is possible to create a training job from 'in-progress' or 'stopped' labeling job.

Comment: You have two options: 1) Consolidate workers responses in `consolidated-annotations` into intermediate output manifest;  2) (preferred option) implement [Active Learning Loop](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/bring-your-own-model-for-amazon-sagemaker-labeling-workflows-with-active-learning/) where you cant set number of objects for each loop.